# Excel Precedents.Count returning incorrect value within cell formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

The Excel property `Precedents.Count` is returning a different value within a cell formula than the value shown when calling the same function within the immediate window.

See below for the function and testing code.

```
Function CountPrecedents()
  CountPrecedents = Range("A1").Precedents.Count
End Function

Sub TestCountPrecedents()
  Range("A1").Formula = "=B1+B2"
  Range("C1").Formula = "=CountPrecedents()"
  Debug.Print "The cell value is " & Range("C1").Value
  Debug.Print "The true function value is " & CountPrecedents()
End Sub
```

Running `TestCountPrecedents` in the Immediate window results in the following output:

```
The cell value is 1
The true function value is 2
```

Why would the cell function have a different value than the immediate window? I cannot replicate this behavior with other `Range` properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of using this Property in a cell-based `UDF()`.

The same UDF will function correctly if called from within a sub:

```
Sub MAIN()
    MsgBox CountPrecedents()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to find another user encountering the same issue in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541342/when-called-from-an-excel-vba-udf-range-precedents-returns-the-range-and-not-it)